# Combine cluster labels from k-means clustering using the consensus function in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, data-analysis, consensus

I have performed k-means clustering on my dataset and now I am trying to combine all the cluster labels from the clustering result using consensus function in R. Can anyone help or give me suggestions on how to do this?

```
set.seed(1234)
runs <- 30
different_run_labels <- matrix(nrow = ncol(data), ncol = runs, 0)
rownames(different_run_labels) <- colnames(data)

for (j in 1:runs) {
  k_means <- kmeans(t(dataset),centers = 6, iter.max = 50, nstart = 5) 
  different_run_labels[,j] <- k_means$cluster
}

# Storing cluster labels.
k_means_clusterlabels <- K_means_Model$cluster
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on what final result you are looking for? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: You do realize that the definition of cluster 1 will be different, completely different, for each run? In run 1 cluster 1 may match most closely cluster 3 from run 2 and cluster 7 from run 3. The cluster numbers are completely arbitrary. How do you plan to do a consensus analysis? You can do all thirty runs with `replicate()`, no need for the loop.